# AS2 - Switching text in Dynamic Text box

Tags: flash, actionscript, text, dynamic

I'm making a very simple adventure game with a dialogue box.

The dialogue box is a dynamic text box. I need it to display the next message everytime the "next" button is pushed.

Right now, this is how it looks.

```
stop();

onEnterFrame = gameProgression();

function gameProgression()
{
if (MessageProgress = 1)
{
    MessageText.text = "Blah blah blah.";
}
else
{
    if (MessageProgress = 2)
    {
        MessageText.text = "More blah.";
    }
    else
    {
        if (MessageProgress = 3)
        {
            MessageText.text = "And again.";
        }
        else
        {
```

And so on and so forth. Every time the "next" button is pressed, +1 is added to the MessageProgress variable.

However, when I try this, it'll display the first message perfectly fine but not display any other message no matter how many times the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `if(MessageProgress = 1)` means you assign Messageprogress as 1.

Use `if(MessageProgress == 1)` to evaluate expression & similarly for other if conditions.

Anyways, The above method is not at all the way to go. Why not put the messages in an array and simply refer to them like Array[0],Array[1]...

---

**EDIT :**

Something like,

```
stop();

onEnterFrame = gameProgression();

myArray = new Array("Blah blah blah.","More Blah.","And Again");

function gameProgression()
{
     // Remember to start MessageProgress from 0 and not 1

     myArray[MessageProgress];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a Switch .. case work faster in this case than an if else ladder?

Comment: Of course. That's why I said 'not the way to go'. Anyways, in the above case we hardly need a conditional branching - An array would suffice.

Comment: Well, I can't use an array as I also plan to change which frame a movie clip is displaying to suit the message.

I tried using a switch case, but I still can't seem to get it to update. It just goes straight to the last case.

Comment: Well, I got it to stop skipping straight to the final case (adding in a break' at the end of each case), but I still can't get it to update to the next case when MessageProgress increases.

Comment: Well, finally got it to work by having the next button call the same function, thus essentially refreshing the function everytime the next button is clicked.

Comment: So the problem was MessageProgress did not change?? Glad that you figured.